# BeagleBone balck GPIO as a data bus

Tags: c, soc

I want to connect a 16 bit fifo chip to the BeagleBone black GPIO pins.
The GPIO needs to be configured as input only, output is not needed except to configure one GPIO as a Read clock to the fifo. This can be bit banged to produce the read clock.
I am new to BagleBone and trying to work out which of the many GPIO pins are the best to use as a 16 bit bus so that the code can do one read of the GPIO's to return 16 bit word per read clock. The read of the fifo must be fairly quick so I dont want to have to write code that does any shifting of bits to get the data lined up to 16 bit.

The application is to burst 16 bit ADC data @ 10Mhz into the fifo and then read the fifo data into the BB for processing.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Which kernel are you using?